# Openshift first call after few hours always fail

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift

I have recently deployed by nodejs ( with mongodb ) server on open shift which is being used by my android application. Every morning the first interaction from the app to the open-shift server always fails to get a response. After that any call made to the server always get a very fast response. I have a feeling that its sort of goes into sleeping mode because of no interaction from app to server for 8 hours or so (sleeping time)... I might be wrong . So I wish to know if someone has experienced that and if yes how do you resolve this . I do not get any logs at server for first call .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using OpenShift Online Starter, you will find this behaviour explained on the product page.

- https://www.openshift.com/products/online/

Quoting it:

> Your project resources sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity, and must sleep 18 hours in a 72 hour period

OpenShift Online Starter is a free tier intended for experimentation and testing. It is not intended for production systems that need to be running permanently.

If you are running a production site, you would want to look at the Pro tier.